# Insert Rows based on the values and update other column?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am new to pandas module and using it for my data analysis at work. I have an excel table, that imports data from access database every day and new records are inserted each time a machine goes down. The table basically shows uptime percentage for each machine

```
ID | Area | Machine | Week | UTPercent
--------------------------------------
1  |  A1  |   M1    |   1  |  80
2  |  A1  |   M1    |   4  |  90
3  |  A2  |   M2    |   4  |  70
4  |  A2  |   M2    |   8  |  82
```

From the above, if the current week is 8, then it has skipped weeks 2,3,5,6,7,8 for Machine1 and 1,2,3,5,6 and 7 for Machine2. How would I add rows in the middle and put UTPercent as 100% accordingly for all these rows? In other words, here is what I need.

```
ID  | Area | Machine | Week | UTPercent
--------------------------------------
1   |  A1  |   M1    |   1  |  80
2   |  A1  |   M1    |   2  |  100
3   |  A1  |   M1    |   3  |  100
4   |  A1  |   M1    |   4  |  90
5   |  A1  |   M1    |   5  |  100
6   |  A1  |   M1    |   6  |  100
7   |  A1  |   M1    |   7  |  100
8   |  A1  |   M1    |   8  |  100
9   |  A1  |   M2    |   1  |  100
10  |  A2  |   M2    |   2  |  100
11  |  A2  |   M2    |   3  |  100
12  |  A2  |   M2    |   4  |  70
13  |  A2  |   M2    |   5  |  100
14  |  A2  |   M2    |   6  |  100
15  |  A2  |   M2    |   7  |  100
16  |  A2  |   M2    |   8  |  82
```

Also, how do I add datalabels, when barplotting for only Machine1 in Area1? I have made bar chart for week (x-axis) vs Uptime Percentage (y-axis). I will need Weeks as my datalabels.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
import matplotlib.plot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("targetFolder.xlsx", sheetname = 0, sep ='|')

area1 = df.loc[df['Area'] == 'A1']

# the data

data = list(area1['UTPercent'])
weekNum = list(df.Week)

## the bars
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
plotData = ax1.bar(weekNum, data, width = 0.45, 
color='#556B2F')

# adding labels and title
ax1.set_xlabel("Weeks")
ax1.set_ylabel("Uptime Percentage")
ax1.set_title("Metrology Area", weight='bold')

fig.tight_layout()
fig.gca()
```

Comment: Deal with your two problems separately: 1) how to go from failure data to "Machine x had uptime y in week z" data. 2) how to plot the last three weeks of that data. 

The first problem is reasoning before it's code: do you already have a complete list of machines, or do they go in and out of service? How do you know when you've read all the data for a given week? Etc. This may be practical knowledge about your workplace.

Comment: Hello cphlewis, I have reframed the question to make it clear. Hope it helps :). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I bet if you kept reframing the question to make it clear to us you would solve it (this is a very natural programming strategy).

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem I'd do something like this (assuming your table is called `uptimes`):

```
INSERT INTO uptimes (Week, Machine, Area, UTPercent)
    (SELECT SeqValue AS Week,
            machines.Machine,
            machines.Area,
            100 AS UTPercent
     FROM
         (SELECT (TWO_1.SeqValue + TWO_2.SeqValue + TWO_4.SeqValue + TWO_8.SeqValue + TWO_16.SeqValue + TWO_32.SeqValue) SeqValue
          FROM
              (SELECT 0 SeqValue
               UNION ALL SELECT 1 SeqValue) TWO_1
          CROSS JOIN
              (SELECT 0 SeqValue
               UNION ALL SELECT 2 SeqValue) TWO_2
          CROSS JOIN
              (SELECT 0 SeqValue
               UNION ALL SELECT 4 SeqValue) TWO_4
          CROSS JOIN
              (SELECT 0 SeqValue
               UNION ALL SELECT 8 SeqValue) TWO_8
          CROSS JOIN
              (SELECT 0 SeqValue
               UNION ALL SELECT 16 SeqValue) TWO_16
          CROSS JOIN
              (SELECT 0 SeqValue
               UNION ALL SELECT 32 SeqValue) TWO_32
          HAVING SeqValue <=
              (SELECT max(week)
               FROM uptimes)
          AND SeqValue > 0) AS integers
     LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT Machine,
                 Area
          FROM uptimes
          GROUP BY 1,
                   2) AS machines ON 1=1
     LEFT JOIN uptimes ON uptimes.week = integers.SeqValue
     AND machines.Machine = uptimes.Machine
     WHERE uptimes.week IS NULL);
```

The way it works:

1. generate integers from 1 to the highest week in you table (SELECT with the unions)
2. Get all machines and areas from your table (SELECT machine, area...)
3. Cross join both to get all possible combinations (JOIN on 1=1)
4. filter out those which already exist (WHERE uptimes.week is null)
5. insert the result into the table (insert into)

For the other problem. Try to use the pandas plot function.

```
df = pd.read_excel("targetFolder.xlsx", sheetname = 0, sep ='|')
area1 = df[df.Area == 'A1']
area1.set_index('Week')['UTPercent'].plot(kind='bar')
```